# If-ElseIf-Else Condition at Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

Let I have a string like **email me at info@domain.com**.

I want to validate the string (using Regex) like

1. string contains **email** or **url** then string must contains **domain.com**
2. string contains **call** then string must contains **10 digit number**

Some Validate String

1. email me at info@domain.com
2. call me at 9874456734
3. I am fine

Some Invalid String

1. email me at info@stackoverflow.com

Till now i am trying

**Script**

```
var str = 'email me at info@domain.com';
var matchEmailUrl = str.match(/email|url/);
var matchCall = str.match(/call/)
var validation = !matchEmailUrl && !matchCall;    

if(!validation){
   if(matchEmailUrl)
      validation = str.match(/domain\.com/)  != null;
   else if(matchCall)
   validation = str.match(/\d{10}/)  != null;
}
```

It works fine but i want to do it a single regex expression.

Comment: ok. where is your code ?

Comment: We could use some code. What have you tried? Or are you just asking us to do it for you?

Comment: Is an empty string also valid?

Comment: most of the time you use the method `match` to check a literal string, it is useless, use `indexOf` instead. (except for the ten digits)

Comment: what about: `my number is 9874456734, call me`

Comment: @RobertSmit, valid string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a single regex to validate your strings:

```
var re = /.*?\b(?:email|url)\b.*?domain\.com|\bcall\b.*?\d{10}|^(?:(?!\b(?:email|url)\b).)+$/i;
```

Use it like:

```js
var re = /.*?\b(?:email|url)\b.*?domain\.com|\bcall\b.*?\d{10}|^(?:(?!\b(?:email|url)\b).)+$/i; 
var str = 'email me at info@domain.com';
if (re.test(str))
  alert(true);
```

Here is an example what this regex will match:

```js
var re = /.*?\b(?:email|url)\b.*?domain\.com|\bcall\b.*?\d{10}|^(?:(?!\b(?:email|url)\b).)+$/igm; 
var str = '\nemail me at info@domain.com\ncall me at 9874456734\nI am fine\n\nemail me at info@stackoverflow.com';
var m;
 
while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    document.getElementById("res").innerHTML += m[0] + "<br/>";
}
```

```html
<div id="res"/>
```

Comment: You might also add `\b` around `domain\.com` just to make sure we do not match `ddomain.comand`.

Comment: Did it help, or do you need more assistance?

Comment: The regex? `/.*?\b(?:email|url)\b.*?domain\.com|\bcall\b.*?\d{10}|^(?:(?!\b(?:email|url)\b).)+$/igm` means *match 3 alternatives*. `.*?\b(?:email|url)\b.*?domain\.com` will match some text, then `email` or `url` then some text then `domain.com`. The second alternative - `\bcall\b.*?\d{10}`- will match `call` then some text then 10 digits at least. The last group - `^(?:(?!\b(?:email|url)\b).)+$` - any line that has no whole word `email` or `url`.